# How to change the legend of each datapoint?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to compare experimental curve against a bunch of simulations data. The simulations tries to replicate a single point of the curve.

I can plot both the curve and the plots together, however the legend isn't what I need.

```
x_simu = AoA_mean
y_simu = Cl_mean

x_exp = AoA_cl_DanAero
y_exp =CL_DanAero

df1 = data.frame(x_simu, y_simu)
df2 = data.frame(x_exp, y_exp)

ggplot(data = df1, mapping = aes(x_simu, y_simu))+
  geom_point(aes(color = y_simu))+
  geom_point(data = df2 ,mapping = aes(x_exp, y_exp))+
  geom_line(data = df2 ,mapping = aes(x_exp, y_exp))
```

[image: ggplot comparing experiment vs simualtions]

I would like that each simulation point get its own color and its own name in the legend.

I feel that I should use the "factor" format of R but I wasn't able to combine the curve with the simulations if I do it.

```
x_simu = as.factor(x_simu)
y_simu = as.factor(y_simu)
ggplot(data = df1, aes(x_simu, y_simu,color = legend_label))+
  geom_point()
```

[image]

I would like to have the legend of the 2nd plot in the 1st plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Factors are no good choice for continuous data. Factors are good for categorical data. Simply add an id variable for each of your simulation points. Try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

# example data
df <- data.frame(
  x_simu = runif(20),
  y_simu = runif(20),
  legend_label = as.factor(1:20)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x_simu, y_simu))+
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(color = legend_label))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Just want I needed, I am angry at myself: hours of search for a simple solution!
Instead of a gradient type of scale for the data, is there a way to have a discrete coloring?

Comment: That's how we learn ... For this I have stopped counting my stupid or simple errors. (;

Answer (score 2):

I've had to work with similar cases myself.  As [u/stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12993861/stefan) mentioned, factors are not the answer here.

In your case, you also have two dataframes.  While you can plot both on one plot keeping the dataframes separate, ggplot2 tends to work best when datasets that are plotted on the same mapping are in one combined dataframe.

First, the data, I'll simulate this the same as [u/stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12993861/stefan), adding in df2:

```
# simu set
df1 <- data.frame(
  x_simu = runif(20),
  y_simu = runif(20),
  legend_label = as.factor(1:20)
)

# exp set
df2 <- data.frame(
  x_exp = runif(20),
  y_exp = runif(20)
)
```

You will first want to combine the two dataframes into one.  I usually go about this with `rbind()`, since it is usually very straightforward, but it depends on the data (there are some other ways to do it).  `rbind()` does require the same columns though, so you need to do a bit of cleaning and adjustment before combining.  Namely, give a "legend_label" column to df1, maintain "x" and "y" as column names, and give an id column to each dataframe to make it easier to split them out for plotting:

```
names(df1)[1:2] <- c('x', 'y')
names(df2)[1:2] <- c('x', 'y')
df2$legend_label <- 'NA'
df1$id <- 'simu'
df2$id <- 'exp'

df <- rbind(df1, df2)
```

THEN you plot your data combined.  You mentioned you wanted the labels applied to the 'simu' dataset, so here I'll create the plot where points and line are plotted for "exp", but only the points + legend label is applied for the "simu" set.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y) +
    geom_point(data=subset(df, id=='exp'), color='gray60') +
    geom_line(data=subset(df, id=='exp')) +
    geom_point(data=subset(df, id=='simu'), aes(color=legend_label))
```

[image]

You see, the point here is to apply the aesthetic to the particular geom call that only applies to `id=='simu'`.  Of course, if you wanted to add the label for everything, you would not need subsetting with `subset()`.

Hope the combination of both our answers helps you out.

Comment: It indeed helped as well, I should have said that both dataframe have different sizes (too easy otherwise...). I think the moethod is to use melt and then rename the data as per your example?